# Create multiple pie charts with same colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am creating two pie charts using ggplot. One pie chart has the information of year 2000 and the other one from 2010. My data frame looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(consumer = c("A","A","A","A","A","A"),
                  producer = c("B","C","D","B","C","D"),
                  value = c(15,26,47,58,23,10),
                  year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2010, 2010, 2010),
                  color = c("red", "blue", "green", "red", "blue", "green"))
```

When using scale_fill_manual(values = dat$color), I do not get the colors according to the producer, but just some random colors of the "color" column.
How can I specify the colors according to the "producer" column?

Edit: Here is the code for the plots

```
A_2000 <- filter(dat, year == 2000)
A2000 <- ggplot(A_2000, aes(x="", y=value, fill=producer)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = dat$color)

A_2010 <- filter(dat, year == 2010)
A2010 <- ggplot(A_2010, aes(x="", y=value, fill=producer)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = dat$color)

ggarrange(A2000, A2010, 
          ncol = 2, nrow = 1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the code you have tried?

Comment: Hi, I edited with the code for the plots!

Answer (score 3):

You need to map the `producer` column to the `fill` aesthetic:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = 1, y = value, fill = producer)) +
  geom_col(position = 'fill') +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
  facet_grid(.~year) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(B = 'gold', C = 'tomato2', D = 'deepskyblue4')) +
  theme_void(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Upvote but since the data has a color column, `fillclrs <- setNames(unique(dat$color), unique(dat$producer))` seems better.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I did that at first, but it looks absolutely horrendous in those bright primary colours and I couldn't bring myself to post it!

Comment: If I use  `fillclrs <- setNames(unique(dat$color), unique(dat$producer))` , should I then write `scale_fill_manual(values = fillclrs)`?